# Passing an array to route link throws missing required parameters error?

Tags: laravel

I have this code in a controller which returns a view with the array I want:

```
$collection = $history->getCollection();
return view('dashPages.serviceHistory', compact('history', 'collection'));
```

I have this link in a blade file which I want to pass the array with:

```
<a href="{{route('viewPDF', $collection)}}" target="_blank">View as PDF</a>
```

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/serviceHistory/pdf/{history}', 'ServiceHistoryController@viewPdf')->name('viewPDF');
```

My problem is that passing the $collection variable in the route in the anchor tag throws a missing required parameters error. I can confirm that the array does have data. Also if I pass it a value such as 123 or "abc" the page loads just fine. Also I am trying to use DomPDF but I don't think that is related to the issue here.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT Here is my entire index function used to load the page:**

```
public function index()
{   
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $history = new ServiceHistory;

    //Check URL for filters
    if(request()->has('completedBy'))
    {
        $history = $history->where(['completedBy' => request('completedBy'), 'user_id' => $user_id]);
    }

    if(request()->has('sort'))
    {
        if(request('sort') == "amount")
        {
            $history = $history->orderByDesc('amount');
        }
        if(request('sort') == "task")
        {
            $history = $history->orderBy('task');
        }
    }

    if(request()->has('receipt'))
    {
        if(request('receipt') == "yes")
        {
            $history = $history->where('receipt', '!=', "");
        }
    }

    //Paginate Results
    $history = $history->paginate(5)->appends([
        'completedBy' => request('completedBy'),
        'sort' => request('sort'),
        'receipt' => request('receipt')
    ]);

    //Get data without pagination stuff
    $collection = $history->getCollection();
    dd($history->getCollection());
    return view('dashPages.serviceHistory', compact('history', 'collection'));
}
```

Comment: Share the `getCollection()` function.

Comment: try to debug `getCollection()`  .. use  `dd($history->getCollection())`  and check what does it return it, may be it doesn't return anything

Comment: I debugged and got the expected results so it is definitely returning something.

Answer (score 0):

try using `<a href="{{route('viewPDF', serialize($collection))}}" target="_blank">View as PDF</a>` instead of `<a href="{{route('viewPDF',($collection))}}" target="_blank">View as PDF</a>`

Hope this help.